# Docker : The export path does not exist on OS X

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, file-sharing, docker-desktop

I'm trying to build a remote project using docker. I have cloned the project using  git and then used the command 
`docker-compose up -d` to run containers.

Then I'm getting this error.

```
ERROR: for audio  Cannot start service audio: b'Mounts denied: \r\nThe paths /data/googleappcred and /data/.aws\r\nare not shared from OS X and are not known to Docker.\r\nYou can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.\r\nSee https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.\r\n.'

ERROR: for postgres  Cannot start service postgres: b'Mounts denied: \r\nThe path /data/postgres\r\nis not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.\r\nYou can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.\r\nSee https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.\r\n.'

ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

[image]

As it suggests I tried to configure following paths through Docker->Preferences

```
/data/postgres  
/data/googleappcred   
/data/.aws
```

but I'm getting this error.

> The export /data/postgres/ path does not exist on OS X

[image]

These are the folders that currently listed under docker file sharing.

[image]

I tried few other alternative workarounds suggested by other developers but nothing could resolve my issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue by following these steps.

1. Create a directory by the name data in the root (`~/data/`)
2. The configure following paths through **Docker->Preferences**
   `/data/postgres`
   `/data/googleappcred`
   `/data/.aws`

The issue has occurred because there was no data folder at the system root.